# How to remove duplicate playing cards from player's hand?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to deal a hand of five cards to a player and score them.  My scoring program seems to be working fine, but I am running into the issue of duplicate cards getting dealt from time to time.  I tried using a while loop to check for duplicate cards, but this seems kind of hackish.  My code is below.  Please keep in mind that I am definitely a neophyte, so the simpler the solution the better!  Thanks so much.

```
// create suits array
$suits = array("996", "997", "998", "999");

// create faces array
$faces = array();
$faces[1] = "1";
$faces[2] = "2";
$faces[3] = "3";
$faces[4] = "4";
$faces[5] = "5";
$faces[6] = "6";
$faces[7] = "7";
$faces[8] = "8";
$faces[9] = "9";
$faces[10] = "10";
$faces[11] = "11";
$faces[12] = "12";
$faces[13] = "13";

// create player's hand 
$card = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{   
    $face_value = shuffle($faces);
    $suit_value = shuffle($suits);
    $card[$i] = $faces[$face_value].$suits[$suit_value];

    $counter = 0;
    while ($counter < 100)
    {
        if (in_array($card[$i], $card))
        {
            $face_value = shuffle($faces);
            $suit_value = shuffle($suits);
            $card[$i] = $faces[$face_value].$suits[$suit_value];
        }
        $counter++;
    }

    print ("<img src=\"../images/4/$card[$i].gif\">");

}
```

Comment: Removing duplicates ? You may use [array_unique](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Comment: By the way you could save 13 lines by using `$faces = range(1,13);` :)

Comment: If you were able to use an answer, could you accept it?

Answer (score 6):

It might be more efficient to simply set up an array that has 52 elements, one for each of the cards.

```
$cards = range(0,51);
shuffle($cards);
$hand = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
  $hand[$i] = $cards[$i];
}
```

Note that you can extract the suit and rank of a card `$i` simply, by doing

```
$suit = $hand[$i] % 4;
$rank = $hand[$i] / 4;
```

This will prevent duplicates.

EDIT: Suit and rank were reversed. They should be correct now.

Comment: I think you have the suit and rank reversed.

Comment: Why yes I did. Thank you, @BrianCain

Comment: This is how I would do it. Create a virtual deck and assign it to an array, and pop from the array when dealing to a player.

Answer (score 1):

Because you said you like it easy, you could create your arrays with range().

To avoid getting duplicate hands, check the $card array with before assigning the new hand.

the new code would look like:

```
// create suits array
$suits = range(996, 999);

// create faces array
$faces = range(0, 13);

// create player's hand  
$card = array();

while ( count($card) < 5 )
{   
    $face_value = shuffle($faces);
    $suit_value = shuffle($suits);
    $newcard = $faces[$face_value].$suits[$suit_value];

    if ( in_array($card, $newcard) ) {
        $card[] = $newcard;
        print ("<img src=\"../images/4/$newcard.gif\">");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely create a deck with all 52 cards in it like so:

```
// create suits array
$suits = range(996, 999);

// create entire deck
$deck = range(0, 51);

shuffle($deck);

// create player's hand
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $suit_value = $suits[$deck[$i] % 4];
    $face_value = floor($deck[$i] / 4) + 1;

    print ("<img src=\"../images/4/{$face_value}{$suit_value}.gif\">");
}
```